# Using Regex to efficiently parse/lex tokens

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, performance

I am trying to find a way to use Regex in .NET to efficiently determine which of several patterns a string matches. If my tokens were of fixed text, I would use a Dictionary<> and simply look them up. However, the tokens may have one or more sequences of digits embedded in them to represent indices. I have several dozen to ~100 such tokens. For a small example, I would like to match one of the following tokens:

```
ORDERID
PRICE(\d+)
QUANTITY(\d+)
DESCRIPTION(\d+)
WEIGHT(\d+)_(\d+)
```

(The imagined use case is that I have a set of name-value pairs and the names use embedded integers to permit repetition. In this example, imagine an order that has multiple lines, and PRICE is the price for the nth line. WEIGHT_ is the weight of the mth individual object of the nth line (imagine the lineitem is a kit of some sort)).

Note that composition of these tokens is outside of my control.

I can efficiently recognize these tokens with something like

```
^(?<oid>ORDERID)|(?<prc>PRICE(\d+))|(?<qty>QUANTITY(\d+)|(?<dsc>DESCRIPTION(\d+)|(?<wght>WEIGHT(\d+)_(\d+)$
```

Note that regular expression matching for a given regular express is linear in the size of the string you are matching, and it shouldn't get more than log n less efficient as I add more tokens.

Now do a match:

```
Match m = r.Match("PRICE44")
```

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, to determine which token was matched from the Regex.Match object, I have to iterate through all of the possibilities:

```
m.Groups["oid"].Success
m.Groups["prc"].Success
m.Groups["qty"].Success
m.Groups["dsc"].Success
m.Groups["wght"].Success
```

The cost grows linearly (or more likely, n log n) with an increased number of tokens. If there were, say, a SuccessGroups collection, I could iterate through that, where it would generally (in my usage) have a single element: the particular group that was matched.

I could write my own parsing algorithm creating a trie or similar data structure, but I am loathe to reimplement something that Regex already implements, but doesn't appear to give me efficient access to.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Compared to the cost of executing the regex iterating the list of Groups should be meaningless right?  What do your benchmarks show?

Comment: Not right. Matching a pre-compiled regex is actually quite efficient: it is a deterministic finite state automaton and its execution is approximately linear in the length of the input string being matched (if your willing to be space-inefficient, it can be strictly linear, but you'll often use a more space efficient structure to determine the next state for a given character of input, which can be linear in the number of possible next characters or log n in the number of next characters).

Comment: I did a simple test with the 80ish tokens I need to recognize. I did  just the match, and then I did the match followed by iterating through the groups to find the one that was successful. The cost of iterating through the groups was approximately equal to the cost of the actual recognition, i.e., together it was twice as long. I found a single matching, on average, took ~3.6uS and with the search for the result, took ~7.5uS.

Comment: I can't see any way to do it with the API available.  It's pretty lame that that it doesn't expose the group name on the Group class.  That would have solved your problem as the groups are returned in the order they are captured.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use groups, it will record the first matched and you can iterate through the matches instead of the tokens
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#matched_subexpression

Comment: There is a group for every group in the regex that _might_ be matched. To iterate through the groups is linear in the number of tokens we are recognizing. The regular expression engine already identified which token was matched, I just want to efficiently extract that information.